# Python 3: How to create a list (or dictionary) from a value in a list inside a dictionary using user's input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Is it possible if I create a list/dictionary from a list inside a dictionary using user's input?

```
E.g.
in the dictionary: {'fruits', 'veggies', 'drinks'}
every key has list:  fruits = ['apple','manggo']
every value has a list (or maybe dict): apple = ['stock':30, 'amount':10]
```

So far I was able to create a list inside a dictionary but I can't create a new list from every value in the list `apple = ['stock':30]`.

My code

```
class Inventory:


    def __init__(self):

        self.dict_inv = dict()
        self.count_inv = int(input("Enter the number of inventories: "))


        for count in range(self.count_inv):

            name_inv = str(input("Enter Inventory #%d: " % (count+1)))
            self.dict_inv[name_inv] = count
            self.dict_inv[name_inv] = []


        for name_inv in self.dict_inv:

            max_item = int(input("How many items in {} " .format(name_inv)))

            for count in range(max_item):

                name_item = str(input("Enter item #%d: " % (count+1)))
                self.dict_inv[name_inv].append(name_item)
                self.dict_inv[name_inv[name_item]] = [] # <-- ERROR

        # PRINTS EVERYTHING 
        for key in self.dict_inv.keys():

            if type(self.dict_inv[key]) is list:
                print("{} is a list" .format(key))
                print("items in {} are {}" .format(key, self.dict_inv[key]))


Inventory()
```

Comment: A note on syntax:
A `dict` is in the form `{key: value}`.
If you want the key to have a list, then it is `{key: [value_list]}`.
If you have `{[value_list]}` that is not a `dict`. It is a `set` containing a `list`.
`[key: value]` will give a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: Why would you overwrite like this: `self.dict_inv[name_inv] = count
            self.dict_inv[name_inv] = []`

Comment: @KevinFang I just removed the one with the 'count'. Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure that it is clear enough what you're trying to do for you to get an answer here. You be better served by reviewing a tutorial on lists and dictionaries, like [this one](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) from the official Python documentation (you might want to start the tutorial [from the beginning](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), since Chapter 5 that I linked to may assume you're already read the first description of lists and their syntax in chapter 3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure you to need to create a class for this. Will this accomplish what you are trying to do?

```
# define a generator that ask the user to enter things until they quit.
def ask(thing):
    user_input = 'x'
    while user_input != 'quit':
        user_input = input("Enter %s or 'quit' to stop: " % (thing))
        if user_input != 'quit':
           yield(user_input)


# use list comprehension to create inventory
inventory = [{c: [ {i: int(input("Enter stock: "))} for i in ask("item")]} for c in ask("category")]

# voila!
print( inventory )
```

Here's what happens when the above code executes:

```
$ python3 inventory.py
Enter category or 'quit' to stop: fruit
Enter item or 'quit' to stop: apples
Enter stock: 45
Enter item or 'quit' to stop: bananas
Enter stock: 23
Enter item or 'quit' to stop: berries
Enter stock: 47
Enter item or 'quit' to stop: quit
Enter category or 'quit' to stop: cars
Enter item or 'quit' to stop: fords
Enter stock: 4
Enter item or 'quit' to stop: toyotas
Enter stock: 7
Enter item or 'quit' to stop: quit
Enter category or 'quit' to stop: quit
[{'fruit': [{'apples': 45}, {'bananas': 23}, {'berries': 47}]}, {'cars': [{'fords': 4}, {'toyotas': 7}]}]
```

I guess you can get that into a class if you want.

Comment: I think so. You'll need to define the generator method `ask()` and set your `inventory` attribute like I do in  my answer.